# The angle between two 3D vectors with a result range 0 - 360

Tags: c#, math, 3d

I'm looking for a way to calculate the angle between three points considered as two vectors (see below):

```
using System.Windows.Media.Media3D;

public static float AngleBetweenThreePoints(Point3D[] points)
{
    var v1 = points[1] - points[0];
    var v2 = points[2] - points[1];

    var cross = Vector3D.CrossProduct(v1, v2);
    var dot = Vector3D.DotProduct(v1, v2);

    var angle = Math.PI - Math.Atan2(cross.Length, dot);
    return (float) angle;
}
```

If you give this the following points:

```
var points = new[]
{
    new Point3D(90, 100, 300),
    new Point3D(100, 200, 300),
    new Point3D(100, 300, 300)
};
```

or the following:

```
var points = new[]
{
    new Point3D(110, 100, 300),
    new Point3D(100, 200, 300),
    new Point3D(100, 300, 300)
};
```

You get the same result. I can see the cross product in the function returns (0, 0, 10000) in the first case, and (0, 0, -10000) in the second but this information gets lost with cross.Length which could never return a -ve result.

What I'm looking for is a result range 0 - 360 not limited to 0 - 180. How do I achieve that?

Comment: The don't subtract from Math.PI which is 180 degrees.  Your results is 0 to 360 so when you subtract from 180 you get a results from +180 to -180.

Comment: In 3D space, the angle between two vectors is defined only between 0 and 180 degrees. In what situation would you want an answer between 180 and 360 degrees? That is easy to define in 2D space as a directed or signed angle, but that does not extend to 3D space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is to provide a reference UP vector:

```
public static float AngleBetweenThreePoints(Point3D[] points, Vector3D up)
{
    var v1 = points[1] - points[0];
    var v2 = points[2] - points[1];

    var cross = Vector3D.CrossProduct(v1, v2);
    var dot = Vector3D.DotProduct(v1, v2);

    var angle = Math.Atan2(cross.Length, dot);

    var test = Vector3D.DotProduct(up, cross);
    if (test < 0.0) angle = -angle;
    return (float) angle;
}
```

This came from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5190354/181622

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for this ?

> θ_radian = arccos ( (​P⋅Q) / ​(∣P∣∣Q∣)​ ​​)   with vectors P and Q
>
> θ_radian = θ_degree * π / 180

**EDIT 0-360 range**

```
angle = angle * 360 / (2*Math.PI);
if (angle < 0) angle = angle + 360;
```

Comment: That was my first solution however it has the same issue. It has a limit on the angle of 0 - 180.

Comment: Well a radian angle is on the [-π;π] interval and a π radian angle is 180 degrees, so yeah, that's your limit of 0-180. But i showed you a formula to convert from radian to degrees.

Comment: arccos has a result range of 0 to PI (not PI * 2). Hence the limit I mentioned of 180.

Answer (score 1):

If the cross product is positive, the angle is between 0 and 180.
If its negative, its between 0 and -180 (or 180 and 360).

A simple if statement can be used to flip the sign on the angle.