# What does the comma mean in the arctan operator?

Tags: vector, angle

I was reading the the answers to the question about finding the angle between 2 vectors in 3D space. [Signed angle between two 3D vectors with same origin within the same plane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5188561/signed-angle-between-two-3d-vectors-with-same-origin-within-the-same-plane). The answer is shown here:

```
atan2((Vb x Va) . Vn, Va . Vb)
```

is exactly what I need, but I don't understand what the commas operator is. I know that the exes and dots are cross products and dot products respectively. I don't think the commas are inner products (same thing as dot products)? Perhaps, it is a syntax of a programming language?

Comment: There is no comma operator there, it's just a function that takes two arguments.

Comment: It's arc tangent of y/x using the signs of arguments to determine the correct quadrant, hence two parameters.

Comment: Unlike arctan, [`atan2`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2) takes two arguments.

Comment: Does that means that this equation is limited to angle on the x,y-plane?

Comment: The "code" that you posted is most certainly not valid C++ code.

Comment: FWIW, that is not compilable code. You cannot overload the dot (`.`) operator to compute the dot product of two geometric vectors. That line is a mix of C++ function `atan2` and mathematical notations that are not valid C++ syntax.

Comment: I'm mostly just interested in the math behind the code. Is it possible to return a signed angle, given two vectors using something similar to the above form?

Comment: The question the snippet was originally posted to wasn't a C++ question, though, and the answer never claimed to have anything to do with C++, so it's no surprise it's not compilable C++. (atan2 exists in a lot of languages.)

Comment: `arctan()` is a function, not an operator. It's no good posting meaningless code and then asking what it means.

Comment: Why is *this* question tagged C++, anyway?

Comment: That's not a meaningless code. I found it elsewhere as the most upvoted answer, and posted here to inquire about the answer. I don't see why all the flaming.

Comment: It is meaningless code **if you tag it as C++**.  From what I can tell from the context where you got it, it is either Matlab code or pseudo-code.  So tagging it as "c++" is actually wasting the time of a bunch of C++ experts ... and **deserving** of flamage for that reason.

Comment: That question must have taken 2 seconds to read. If you cannot afford 2 seconds of your time, why are you on stackoverflow community trying to answer questions? The whole point of this community is to share answers and help each other. Also, I AM working on c++, hence the tag.

Comment: *"The whole point of this community is to share answers and help each other."*  - Which does not excuse people from using their common sense when asking questions.  The fact that people are generally here to be helpful does not mean that you can *abuse* their good will by wasting their time.  And it doesn't give you any standing to complain when they are annoyed by that.

Comment: *"Also, I AM working on c++"* - That is irrelevant.  The tags are supposed to be used to indicate the topic of the question itself.  And in this case, 1) the code is clearly not C++, and the question is clearly not about C++.  Basically, you used the tag for no reason that stands up to logical scrutiny - which respect to how tags are designed to be used.  Anyhow, you said "I don't see why all the flaming" ... and this is the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The language is (I think<sup>1</sup>) Matlab, and the comma is actually an argument separator (NOT an operator<sup>2</sup>) in a method call.

---

<sup>1 - This is consistent with the context where you found this expression, though I suspect that the author was actually using Matlab syntax as a way of expressing a mathematical concept.</sup>

<sup>2 - According to https://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/matlab-operators-and-special-characters.html</sup>