# Angle between 2 Lines in 3D

Tags: swift, scenekit

i know how to get Angles with atan2 between 2 Points in 2D, but how does this work in 3D?:
lets say i have 3 Points A,B,C (all are SCNVector3 with x,y,z coordinates
First Line Endpoints A and B
2nd Line Endpoints B and C
Now i want to get the angle between the 2 Lines... (in ios Swift)
I read something about the dot product and acos but somehow it does not work...

With i=0:

```
        var vector1 = SCNVector3((pointArray[i].x - pointArray[i+1].x), (pointArray[i].y - pointArray[i+1].y), (pointArray[i].z - pointArray[i+1].z))
        var vector2 = SCNVector3((pointArray[i+2].x - pointArray[i+1].x), (pointArray[i+2].y - pointArray[i+1].y), (pointArray[i+2].z - pointArray[i+1].z))
        var dotProduct = vector1.x * vector2.x + vector1.y * vector2.y + vector1.z * vector2.z
        var theta = acos(dotProduct)
        var tmp_winkel = GLKMathRadiansToDegrees(theta)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the [dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product#Geometric_definition) takes the norm (magnitude) of the vectors into account. Make sure you deal with unit vectors, or divide by the product of their norms.

```
import SceneKit
import simd

var vector1 = float3((pointArray[i].x - pointArray[i+1].x), (pointArray[i].y - pointArray[i+1].y), (pointArray[i].z - pointArray[i+1].z))
var vector2 = float3((pointArray[i+2].x - pointArray[i+1].x), (pointArray[i+2].y - pointArray[i+1].y), (pointArray[i+2].z - pointArray[i+1].z))
var dotProduct = dot(normalize(vector1), normalize(vector2))
var theta = acos(dotProduct)
```

or

```
var vector1 = float3((pointArray[i].x - pointArray[i+1].x), (pointArray[i].y - pointArray[i+1].y), (pointArray[i].z - pointArray[i+1].z))
var vector2 = float3((pointArray[i+2].x - pointArray[i+1].x), (pointArray[i+2].y - pointArray[i+1].y), (pointArray[i+2].z - pointArray[i+1].z))
var dotProduct = dot(vector1, vector2)
var theta = acos(dotProduct / (length(vector1) * length(vector2)))
```

Comment: ah i see, forgot to do the normalize, Thanks!! Problem remaining: direction of the angle... how can i find out if it is clockwise or counterclockwise?

Comment: the cross product can help, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5188561/signed-angle-between-two-3d-vectors-with-same-origin-within-the-same-plane

Comment: @mnuages I need some help on getting angles between numbers of lines with the SCNVector3 array? It will be very helpful to me.

Answer (score 1):

so for getting the direction i do now (thanks mnuages for the hint):

```
var vectorn = cross(normalize(vector1), normalize(vector2))
if (vectorn.y > 0) { //righ hand side }
else { //left hand side}
```

Comment: In which library i will get cross function i have imported "simd" library but it is showing me error

Comment: @YogeshDalavi https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53282351/arkit-add-2d-video-flipped-by-x/53313515#53313515