# ARKit add 2D Video flipped by X

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, arkit

So I have following code to create custom wall

```
    let wall = SCNPlane(width: CGFloat(distance),
                        height: CGFloat(height))
    wall.firstMaterial = wallMaterial()
    let node = SCNNode(geometry: wall)

    // always render before the beachballs
    node.renderingOrder = -10

    // get center point
    node.position = SCNVector3(from.x + (to.x - from.x) * 0.5,
                               from.y + height * 0.5,
                               from.z + (to.z - from.z) * 0.5)
    node.eulerAngles = SCNVector3(0,
                                  -atan2(to.x - node.position.x, from.z - node.position.z) - Float.pi * 0.5,
                                  0)
```

And Now I am adding simple SCNPlane on hit test and add video (skscene to it)

```
          // first.node is hittest result 

            let node = SCNNode(geometry: SCNPlane(width: CGFloat(width) , height:  CGFloat(height))
            node.geometry?.firstMaterial?.isDoubleSided = true
            node.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = self.create2DVideoScene(xScale: first.node.eulerAngles.y < 0 ? -1 : nil)
                         node.position = nodesWithDistance.previous.node.mainNode.position
        
            node.eulerAngles = first.node.eulerAngles
```

Here How I created 2d  node

```
 /// Creates 2D video scene
    private func create2DVideoScene (xScale:CGFloat?) -> SKScene {
        var videoPlayer = AVPlayer()

        if let validURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "video", withExtension: "mp4", subdirectory: "/art.scnassets") {
            let item = AVPlayerItem(url: validURL)
            videoPlayer = AVPlayer(playerItem: item)
        }
        let videoNode = SKVideoNode(avPlayer: videoPlayer)
        videoNode.yScale *= -1
        
        // While debug I observe that if first.node.rotation.y in  - , then we need to change xScale to -1 (when wall draw from right -> left )
        
        if let xScale = xScale {
            videoNode.xScale *= xScale

        }
        
        
        videoNode.play()
        
        let skScene = SKScene(size: self.sceneView.frame.size)
        skScene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
        skScene.backgroundColor = .green
        skScene.addChild(videoNode)
        videoNode.position = CGPoint(x: skScene.size.width/2, y: skScene.size.height/2)
        videoNode.size = skScene.size
        return skScene
    }
```

**Issue**  :: If I draw wall node from left to right means first point is on left side and other point on right side and draw wall between them. Then Video is flipped.

If I draw from right to left means first point is on right side and second point is on left side and draw line between them then video is perfectly fine.

To fix this I checked wall eulerAngles check the line `self.create2DVideoScene` but this is not working in every area of real world

I want video should not be start flipped in front of user

**EDIT**

video is flipped because of `eulerAngles` is different in both case while create a wall

> Angle point1 to point2 --> (0.000000 -1.000000 0.000000 3.735537)
>
> Angle point2 to point1 -- > (0.000000 -1.000000 0.000000 0.478615)

---

Issue video [Click here to play video](https://vimeo.com/300709584)

Please please provide the suggestion or solution of this issue .

[image]

**Video flipped**

[image: Flipped]

Comment: Note that in recent versions of SceneKit using a `SKScene` and a `SKVideoNode` is not necessary. You can directly set the `AVPlayer` as the contents of a `SCNMaterialProperty` instance.

Comment: @mnuages Thanks for comment   I have already tried this. I have already added video i.e AVplayer directly but issue is drawing wall from RIGHT -> LEFT working fine but drawing LEFT -> RIGHT show AVPlayer Flipped

Comment: Issue is with -atan2(to.x - node.position.x, from.z - node.position.z) - Float.pi * 0. but i am not able to figure it out

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "draw from left to right" versus "draw from right to left"

Comment: @mnuages sorry for my bad English 
See the image where I written point 1 and point 2.
If I draw point 1 ---> point 2 video is normal.
But at same position if I draw from point 2 --> point 1 video is flipping as shown in image 2

Comment: @mnuages issue is because of wall's eulerAngles is different  Can you help

Comment: I still don't understand the problem. Please provide details about what you mean by "draw from left to right" versus "draw from right to left".

Comment: @mnuages https://vimeo.com/300709584 please play this once

Comment: @mnuages Do you want me to add more info ? Do you know solution. Issue is with only wall node. I have added material image with text and found that text it self is flipped so I need to change angle or something but I am not able to figure it out

Comment: @mnuages I have solved it by  hack not proper but working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed issue with temporary solution still looking for a better one

Issue is of wall. wall is flipped other side of camera when draw from right to left direction. I have figure it out by setting isDoubleSided = false and by applying a image as diffuse contents   which has text and I can see that image is flipped itself.

I have tried many things but this one helps me

1. Normalize vector
2. Find the cross between to SCNVectors
3. If y > 0 I just swapped from and to Value

Code

```
    let normalizedTO = to.normalized()
    let normalizedFrom = from.normalized()
    let angleBetweenTwoVectors = normalizedTO.cross(normalizedFrom)

    var from = from
    var to = to
    if angleBetweenTwoVectors.y > 0 {
        let temp = from
        from = to
        to = temp
    }

// Inside extension of SCNVector3
func normalized() -> SCNVector3 {
    if self.length() == 0 {
        return self
    }

    return self / self.length()
}

func cross(_ vec: SCNVector3) -> SCNVector3 {
        return SCNVector3(self.y * vec.z - self.z * vec.y, self.z * vec.x - self.x * vec.z, self.x * vec.y - self.y * vec.x)
    }
```

Hope it is helpful. If anyone know better solution please answer it.