# determine whether two points with known normals are facing each other or not (matlab)

Tags: matlab, space, points, normals

I am trying to find a solution to the following problem but it is not clear how to solve it. Imagine that I have the following points in the space as in the image below:

[image]

If I consider that my only known information is the point positions and their normals I would like to determine whether two points (considering as a reference the position of the first point) are facing each other or not. For example from the above image for points `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` and `e` I have:

Point `a` faces points `c` and `e` but not points `b` and `d`.

Point `b` faces points `d` and `e` but not points `a` and `c`.

Point `c` faces point `a` but not points `b`, `d` and `e`.

Point `d` faces points `b` and `e` but not points `a` and `c`.

and finaly

Point `e` faces points `a`, `b` and `d` but not point `c`.

My first though was to play with the signed angles between the two normal vectors of each pair by using the solutions proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5188561/signed-angle-between-two-3d-vectors-with-same-origin-within-the-same-plane/33920320) but this works for some pairs while not for others. The idea regarding what two point are facing each other is that if we consider a point as the origin then it faces another point if the other point is within the origin point's 180 degrees field of view and its normal vector is going inwards (kind of "towards") the origin point.

Any ideas what could help.

Thanks.

---

Update:

to try to be a bit more clear and answer some of the comments below. In principle its point in the space corresponds to the centroid of a face. However, I do not have this information beforehand (i.e. that each point corresponds to the center of a face, or the list of faces and their vertices). So in a higher level, if we were dealing with faces the problem would be how to determine if two faces are visible to each other or not but as I said the only information that I have now are the actual points in the space and their normals.

[image]

Sample points:

```
a = [26415.3720833199 11986.0504166605 739];
na = [0 0 1];

b = [27263.8100000023 11103.1983333336 1512.50000000021];
nb = [0.102791963903622 -0.994702876318771 0];

c = [28059.5700000001 11185.4316666667 962.499999999998];
nc = [-0.102791963903623 0.994702876318771 -9.06557542353252e-16];

d = [26606.7112499615 10390.7487916521 739];
nd = [0 0 1];

e = [27792.4499999996 9225.36499999984 2782];
ne = [0 0 -1];
```

Comment: I dont understand the rules. Why does a faces c and e and not b and d? Its not clear from the picture

Comment: I don't get the 'points are facing'. For me two point are always facing. Also a normal is defined for me relative to a surface. Please explain. Please provide an example with 3 points (should be enough, if no, provide more), their coordinates and what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @all I added some more info. @Ander Biguri `a` faces `c` and `e` because if we set a plane at point `a` with a normal same as point `a` then both are within the 180 degrees FOV and pointing inwards. On the other hand point `b` is within the FOV but pointing outwards and point `d` lies on the same plane and also points towards the same direction as point `a`. @PTRK when I am saying "facing" is like that according to their normals are seeing each other or not. You are right that all points are facing each other but according to their normals some of them should not. I hope I am clear.

Comment: @ThT while I dont really get it, you just described the mathematical method you need to solve it. Define `isinFOV(a,b)` and `pointingDirection(a,b,na,nb)` and you got your answer

Comment: @AnderBiguri how do you define the `pointingDirection(a,b,na,nb)` can you elaborate a bit.

Comment: The same way you define it in your comment. What does it mean to you to point "outwards"? That the the point is in the negative direction of the normal? If that is so, then code that. You know the normal, and the position of the point. If you define properly what you mean with your comments, then you inmediately have the code to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can solve your problem with a few simple [dot products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product)...

Based on your description, a point `b` is within the field of view (FOV) of another point `a` if the angle between the normal of `a` (i.e. `na`) and a vector going from `a` to `b` is less than or equal to 90 degrees. As described [here](https://www.wikihow.com/Find-the-Angle-Between-Two-Vectors), the angle can be found by taking the [dot product](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dot.html) of `b-a` and `na`, dividing by the [length](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/norm.html) of `b-a` (and assuming the length of `na` is already 1), and taking the [inverse cosine](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/acosd.html) of the result. Putting it into an [anonymous function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html), you have:

```
isInFOV = @(b, a, na) (acosd(dot(b-a, na)./norm(b-a)) <= 90);
```

You can then define a point `b` as "pointing toward" another point `a` if the component of `nb` (the normal of `b`) running along the vector going from `b` to `a` is positive. As described [here](http://www.leadinglesson.com/component-along-a-vector), the component can be found by taking the [dot product](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dot.html) of `a-b` and `nb` and dividing by the [length](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/norm.html) of `a-b` (and assuming the length of `nb` is already 1). Putting it into an [anonymous function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html), you have:

```
isPointingToward = @(b, nb, a) (dot(a-b, nb)./norm(a-b) > 0);
```

We can then define whether a point `a` is "facing" another point `b` as:

```
isFacing = @(a, na, b, nb) (isInFOV(b, a, na) && isPointingToward(b, nb, a));
```

Note that I used the [logical short circuit AND operator](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/logicaloperatorsshortcircuit.html) `&&` since `isPointingToward` doesn't need to be evaluated if `isInFOV` already evaluates to `false`.

### Vectorizing

You can reformulate the above equations to vectorize the operations, using functions like [`bsxfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) or replacing a call to [`dot`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dot.html) with standard matrix operations. This will allow you to check which points in a set a given point is facing. A vectorized version of the function `isFacing` is given below:

```
function index = isFacing(a, na, b, nb)

  V = bsxfun(@minus, b, a);                     % Compute b-a for all b
  V = bsxfun(@rdivide, V, sqrt(sum(V.^2, 2)));  % Normalize each row
  index = (acosd(V*na.') <= 90);                % Find points in FOV of a
  index(index) = (sum(V(index, :).*nb(index, :), 2) < 0);  % Of those points in FOV,
                                                           %   find those pointing
                                                           %   towards a

end
```

### Example

Using the sample data in the question:

```
pointMat = [26415.3720833199 11986.0504166605 739; ...               % Point a
            27263.8100000023 11103.1983333336 1512.50000000021; ...  % Point b
            28059.5700000001 11185.4316666667 962.499999999998; ...  % Point c
            26606.7112499615 10390.7487916521 739];                  % Point d
normalMat = [0 0 1; ...
             0.102791963903622 -0.994702876318771 0; ...
             -0.102791963903623 0.994702876318771 -9.06557542353252e-16; ...
             0 0 1];
p = [27792.4499999996 9225.36499999984 2782];  % Point e
np = [0 0 -1];

>> isFacing(p, np, pointMat, normalMat)

ans =

  4×1 logical array

   1    % Facing a
   1    % Facing b
   0    % Not facing c
   1    % Facing d
```

Comment: @ gnovice thanks a lot, really neat solution :-). I added the sample points as well for the future readers if they want to try it by themselves. I learned also about the anonymous functions. I did not have any idea about them. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @ gnovice can I pass the isFacing (which is anonymous) as an input to a bsxfun so that I vectorize the logical output of one point with all the rest points where I provide the coordinates and the normals of all other points as two `n x 3` vectors. Thus, to avoid the for loop. I am trying it now but it seems not to work.

Comment: @ThT: Applying `bsxfun` to the anonymous functions won't work in this case. You have to modify the underlying equations to account for the multiple points. I've added a vectorized version to the answer.

Comment: @ gnovice I see. Thank you for the vectorized solution as well ;-).